# How to iterate through class name, so if two or more elements have the same data attributes they can have the same ID using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to loop through the number of element with the class name `category` but if there is an element with the same data attribute value for `data-sector-colour`. I want them to have the same ID value as the first value.

For example:

```
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341" data-id='1'>Energy 1</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341" data-id='1'>Energy 2</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341" data-id='1'>Energy 3</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#fff" data-data-id='2'>Politics</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#000" data-id='3'>Work</h2>
```

Should output to:

```
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341" data-id='1'>Energy 1</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341" data-id='1'>Energy 2</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341" data-id='1'>Energy 3</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#fff" data-id='2'>Politics</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#000" data-id='3'>Work</h2>
```

So far this is the HTML:

```
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341" id='1'>Energy 1</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341" >Energy 2</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341" >Energy 3</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#fff" id='2'>Politics</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#000" id='3'>Work</h2>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(".category").each(function (i) {
  if ($(this).attr("data-sector-colour").length > 1) {
    console.log($(this).attr("data-sector-colour"));
    
  }
});
```

I am have problems get the elements where `data-sector-colour="#7e1341"` so they can have the same id as the first one.

The codepen to my problem is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/VweWgwo

Comment: (1) Where are you trying to *set* that ID value?  Have you tried `$(this).prop('id', someValueHere)`?  (2) Duplicated ID values will make your markup invalid, which is likely to cause problems downstream.  [Whatever problem you're trying to solve](http://xyproblem.info/) by doing this, this is not how you solve it.

Comment: Can you also explain what are you trying to build? Otherwise you might end up asking for an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const $category = $(".category");

// Start with the ones who already have a data-id
$("[data-id]").each(function() {
  const dataID = this.dataset.id;
  const sectorColour = this.dataset.sectorColour;
  
  // Now you can iterate and assign data-id to the ones with the same colour:
  $category
    .filter((i, el) => el.dataset.sectorColour === sectorColour)
    .attr({"data-id": dataID});

});
```

```css
[data-id='1'] {color: red; }
```

```html
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341" data-id='1'>Energy 1</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341" >Energy 2</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341" >Energy 3</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#fff" data-id='2'>Politics</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#000" data-id='3'>Work</h2>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's where `data-attributes` are for. They can have duplicate values, whereas element ids can not. You can retrieve (and use) all elements with a certain value for `data-sector-colour` using [plain js](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) (`document.querySelectorAll`), something like this

```js
const allColour7e1341 = document.querySelectorAll("[data-sector-colour='#7e1341']");

// let's set the color, using the data-attribute
allColour7e1341.forEach(c => c.style.color = c.dataset.sectorColour);

// or by className
document.querySelectorAll(".category")
  .forEach( elem => {
    if ( elem.dataset.sectorColour && 
      elem.dataset.sectorColour !== "#7e1341" ) {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = elem.dataset.sectorColour;
      }
    });
```

```html
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341">Energy 1</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341">Energy 2</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#7e1341">Energy 3</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#ffffc0">Politics</h2>
<h2 class="category" data-sector-colour="#c0c0c0">Work</h2>
```